# A * B computation when B is a symmetric matrix in armadillo

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, armadillo, blas

Is there any way to multiply a symmetric matrix by a dense one in armadillo(and use the fact that we have a symmetric matrix)? I know about `DSYMM` Routine in BLAS,but the matrices I'm dealing with are `mat` type(they are not arrays),So I wonder if there is some thing in armadillo using `DSYMM` Routine from BLAS.
I couldn't find any thing in armadillo documentation.

Comment: Armadillo internally uses BLAS for matrix multiplication. While building your executable, if you link it with the appropriate libraries, it should exploit the fact that one of the matrices is symmetric while doing multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files `include/armadillo_bits/def_blas.hpp` (BLAS interface) and `include/armadillo_bits/glue_times_meat.hpp` (implementing the multiplication) in the source distribution do not reference `dsymm` at all (in contrast to `dgemm`) so even though your matrices might be symmetric, the multiplication won't take advantage of this.

However, should you need to use `dsymm`, you might use the [`memptr()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#memptr) method of the matrices to obtain access to the raw contiguous memory and call `dsymm` directly yourself...

Comment: Great,Thank you so much.